# Generate random letters using Jinja for cookiecutter template

Tags: python, jinja2, cookiecutter

I am looking to generate a random 8 letter hash for a cookeicutter template.  In pure Python, this would generate what I'd like:

```
In [3]: import random
In [3]: import string
In [4]: ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(8))                                                                                        
Out[4]: 'jrqcwtav'
```

In Jinja, the closest thing I could find would be a multiline solution.  I need a one-liner. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `cookiecutter>=1.7`, you can use filter `random_ascii_string` like this :

```yaml
{{ random_ascii_string(8) }}
```

More information available about [random_ascii_string](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/template_extensions.html#random-string-extension).

Answer (score 0):

In plain Jinja2 you can achieve the same using

```
{% macro random_string(len) -%}{% for i in range(0,len) -%}{{ [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"a","b","c","d","e","f"]|random }}{% endfor %}{%- endmacro -%}
{% macro random_guid() -%} {{ random_string(8) + "-" + random_string(4) + "-" + random_string(4) + "-" + random_string(4) + "-" + random_string(12) }}{%- endmacro -%}
{% set myGUID = random_guid() %}
```

More info here: https://isbyr.com/create-random-guid-with-jinja/